# Object field does not save

Tags: php

I am creating a Tree where each nodeParent objects can have subParents and children. Inside a while loop I am instantiating a nodeParent object (because i get the input from a file) and then I am adding its children(subParents and children) using a stack for determining the root. I added each root parent in an Array so i can get go through the tree, but when I try to access their subParents name i get no output. 
Here is the NodeParent class:

```
class NodeParent
     private $name;
     private $subParents=array();
     private $children=array();

     function setName($name){
         $this->name=$name;
     }
     function addChild($child){
         $this->children = $child;
     }
     function addParent($parent){
         $this->subParents = $parent;
     }
     function getName(){
         return $this->name;
     }
     function getSubParents(){
         return $this->subParents;
     }
     function getChildren(){
         return $this->children;
     }
}
```

And here is when I am adding for each NodeParent object their subParents:

```
$size = $stack->getSize();
            $subParent = new NodeParent();
            $subParent -> setName($name);
            $parent = $stack->peek();

            $parent -> addParent($subParent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements should be added to the array, you are currently overwriting the array with an `NodeParent` instance. Pushing to an array can be achieved with the following:

```
class NodeParent
     private $name;
     private $subParents=array();
     private $children=array();

     function setName($name){
         $this->name=$name;
     }
     function addChild($child){
         $this->children[] = $child;
     }
     function addParent($parent){
         $this->subParents[] = $parent;
     }
     function getName(){
         return $this->name;
     }
     function getSubParents(){
         return $this->subParents;
     }
     function getChildren(){
         return $this->children;
     }
}
```